# Using systemd to run airflow inside conda environment

Tags: linux, systemd, anaconda

I configured an Airflow server installed within a conda environment to run some scheduled automations. Currently, I launch the scheduler, workers and webserver directly using `nohup`, but I'd like to use systemd to manage it more robustly.

However, I'm having trouble launching the system with `systemctl start`. I added to my `.service` file the following:

```
ExecStartPre=. /etc/profile ; /home/shared/miniconda2/bin/conda activate airflow
ExecStart=/home/shared/miniconda2/envs/airflow/bin/airflow webserver --pid /run/airflow/webserver.pid
```

(where `shared/` is not a user, just a folder inside `/home/` to which all users have access)

`ExecStart` requires the `airflow` conda environment in which airflow is actually installed to be activated. To do this, I added the two commands seen in `ExecStartPre`: the second one actually activates this environment. Running this alone returns `CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.`, so I added the first one to ensure `/etc/profile.d/conda.sh` is loaded.

However, this still fails, seemingly while trying to run the Gunicorn Server:

```
Running the Gunicorn Server with:
Workers: 4 sync
Host: 0.0.0.0:8080
Timeout: 120
Logfiles: - -
=================================================================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shared/miniconda2/envs/airflow/bin/airflow", line 28, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/home/shared/miniconda2/envs/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 844, in webserver
    gunicorn_master_proc = subprocess.Popen(run_args)
  File "/home/shared/miniconda2/envs/airflow/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/home/shared/miniconda2/envs/airflow/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1025, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

(timestamps omitted to improve readability a bit)

This raises a number of questions:

- What might be causing my service to fail?
- Is my setup nonsensical (systemd + conda + airflow)?
- If it is nonsensical, is there a better way to run airflow more robustly than launching it directly? I was particularly interested in the `enable` and `restart` options that systemd offers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope by now you have solved your problem but for reference here is my solution.

The way I solved it was to add a level of indirection for launching airflow. I have a bash script e.g. `airflow_runner.sh` with the following

```
conda activate airflow-env
$AIRFLOW_BIN/airflow $@
```

Then in my systemd unit file

```
ExecStart=PATH_TO_SCRIPT/airflow_runner.sh webserver --pid /run/airflow/webserver.pid
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just moved on to a docker implementation of Airflow, which got rid of the issues I was having. Regardless, I'll take your word that it works and accept it. Welcome to SuperUser.